# Mysql query with in limited value but it must be max overall value

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

My current Mysql query is

```
SELECT max(login_time) FROM login_time_table WHERE login_time >='2014-10-12' AND login_time <= '2014-10-14' group by user_id"
```

It provides all the data maximum with in that group and limit date provided there but 
I need the login_time must be with in the date provided in where condition and it must be max with in the whole table not only within that range provided in that query.

eg:- let my data be
[image]

I want id 362,361 as my answer but
it provides 362,361 and 361

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data set together with expected result set

Comment: Why not record 360? There are three user IDs in that excerpt, you want the max for each one right?

Comment: becuse it's max login date is in 363 @miken32

Comment: and I want the user id whose last login date is with in that date

Comment: You said "I want id 362,361 as my answer" so my question is the same, though I mistyped the record number. Why not record 363?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63299/discussion-between-anil-bhattarai100-and-miken32).

Comment: the 363 exceeds the date that I have provided in my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does this work?

```
SELECT user_id, login_time
FROM login_time_table
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING MAX(login_time) >='2014-10-12' AND MAX(login_time) <= '2014-10-14';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you are asking. You want to use HAVING instead of WHERE.

HAVING applies the filter AFTER the group by, so you can select the max login time for each user, and then filter out the ones that aren't in the range:

```
SELECT max(login_time) AS max_time FROM login_time_table GROUP BY user_id HAVING max_time >='2014-10-12' AND max_time <= '2014-10-14' group by user_id
```

Note that by using <= '2014-10-14' it won't actually include login times for 2014-10-14, because any time after midnight is greater than '2014-10-14'. I think you might want:

```
SELECT max(login_time) AS max_time FROM login_time_table GROUP BY user_id HAVING max_time >='2014-10-12' AND max_time < '2014-10-15' group by user_id
```